# Pound-Rebka Experiment

Tags: general-relativity, velocity, frequency, wavelength

I am new here and have a question.

Does anyone know if the velocity of the photons changes in the [Pound-Rebka experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Rebka_experiment)?

Do the wavelength and the frequency change simultaneously, so that there is no change in the velocity, or do they change differently and there was/would be a recognizable velocity change?

This is the Equation I want to understand:

f * λ = c

Thanks, I hopefully haven't missed a previous answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

In a local inertial frame at any point along the light’s path the light will travel at $c$. So, yes, both the wavelength and the frequency will change relative to momentarily comoving inertial frames at the emission and reception events.

This can be understood as a Doppler shift as the momentarily comoving inertial frame at the emission event is moving with respect to the momentarily comoving inertial frame at the reception event.